# Can't get draggable/droppable work in shopify library

Tags: javascript, shopify, draggable

I couldn't get [shopify/draggable](https://github.com/Shopify/draggable) work for me. Actually I just need to

1. Drag an element
2. Catch when it's dropped on a canvas
3. Do some stuff on canvas

I tried to work just with divs and here is my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/1v4eL8oz/6/

```
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.block')

const droppable = new Draggable.Droppable(containers, {
  draggable: '.draggable',
  droppable: '.droppable'
});

droppable.on('drag:start', () => console.log('drag:start'));
droppable.on('droppable:over', () => console.log('droppable:over'));
droppable.on('droppable:out', () => console.log('droppable:out'));
```

I noticed that drag:start gets fired, and that's it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It is big loss of library an even bigger - of their documentation, but, when you use *Droppable*, you need to cover any your *Draggable* elements to *Droppable* containers, like it is the another dropzones. But, for those containers including your *Draggable* elements, it is some rules:

1. It can be only one *Draggable* element inside;
2. It need to be with **draggable-dropzone--occupied** class;
3. It need to be in *containers* div or element, like anything about *Draggable* or *Droppable*.

So, your jsfiddle need to look somehow like this:

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.block')

const droppable = new Draggable.Droppable(containers, {
  draggable: '.draggable',
  droppable: '.droppable'
});

droppable.on('drag:start', () => console.log('drag:start'));
droppable.on('droppable:over', () => console.log('droppable:over'));
droppable.on('droppable:out', () => console.log('droppable:out'));
```

```css
.draggable, .droppable.draggable-dropzone--occupied{
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
}
.droppable{
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shopify/draggable@1.0.0-beta.5/lib/draggable.bundle.js"></script>

<div class="block">
      <div style="background-color: black" class="droppable draggable-dropzone--occupied">
        <div style=" background-color: red" class="draggable"></div>
      </div>
</div>
    
<div class="block">
      <div style="background-color: #eee" class="droppable"></div>
    </div>
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/s3om12g9/)

It was explained [here](https://github.com/Shopify/draggable/issues/85#issuecomment-341529512)